# Ubuntu 14.04 does not indicate my discrete GPU

Tags: drivers, graphics, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee, bios

After installing [Bumblebee](http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/bumblebee) and Nvidia 331.38 driver with primus I get this error

> delmomd@Dell:~$ optirun steam
>
> [  887.242992] [ERROR]The Bumblebee daemon has not been started yet or the socket path /var/run/bumblebee.socket was incorrect.
>
> [  887.243047] [ERROR]Could not connect to bumblebee daemon - is it running?

After searching for solution on the internet I've found out that Ubuntu does not detect my Nvidia card. I haven't found any way to turn on optimus in BIOS. Any ideas how I can detect my GPU and use Bumblebee again? Funny thing is that I had this problem on SteamOS too, that's why I've returned to Ubuntu.

My laptop: Dell inspiron 7720, GPU: Nvidia Geforce 650M

EDIT: That's one of the ways I've discovered that Ubuntu does not detect my card:

> delmomd@Dell:~$ sudo bumblebeed restart
>
> [sudo] password for delmomd:
>
> [  649.003957] [ERROR]No discrete video card found, quitting

Comment: It is happening the same to me, with Nvidia drivers 304 and a Dell Vostro 2420 (Geforce GT 620M)

Comment: @José Someone said that problem may be solved by complete shutdown and removing battery for like 10 minutes. This is not a solution for me as long as my battery is broken and I'm not using it at all. I am going to replace it with a good one and then try to do things again. Please inform me if this helps you somehow.